# How to show popup window on screentouch in webview in android?

Tags: android, webview, popupwindow

i am in webview right now, well i struggling to show pop-up window on webview. i have to show pop-up window everytime when i touch on the webview at the extact same location where i touched, i tried with the ontouchlistener but still i can't the pop-up view. Can you guys help me to solve this problem, Thanks in advance. Below is my code.

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            touch();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            touch();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});

public void touch() {
    View popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);                                                                         
    mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
    mpopup.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
    mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);

    Button option = (Button) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.sign);
    option.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mpopup.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(View.this,
                Capture.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    Button btnOk = (Button) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mpopup.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

App gets crashed on touching webview.

popup.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/sign"
      android:layout_width="160dp"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/camera"
      android:text="button" >
  </Button>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/date"
      android:layout_width="160dp"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:text="button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat message?

Comment: Well, i didn't get any exception it just crashes.

Comment: i will update my question with logcat can you wait please.

Comment: @SLee ya its true i am not getting any exception but the popup doesn't display, can you analyse my code and tel me whats wrong with it.

Comment: Does your app crash or it just does not display your popup window? Also, it could crash since you are calling touch method for every motion events.

Comment: is not crashing and pop-up window doesn't show.

Comment: Did you check whether your touch method gets called? Creating popup window part looks fine. Lastly, can you post your popup.xml file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67229/discussion-between-rinnegan-naruto-and-slee).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   mpopup = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null, false), 100, 100, true);

    // Show the Popup
    mpopup.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

You layout (root container) must have the id set, for example:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webViewEx1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i am getting NullPointerException from your code excatly @mpopup.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

Comment: Did you add the ID to your layout?

Comment: ya i did exactly what you told?

Comment: can you change my above code, the changes you subscribed in touch method.

Comment: My bad, the root container (your activity that will present the webview needs to have the ID set instead of your popup layout, I will update my response and please try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67231/discussion-between-rinnegan-naruto-and-azael).

Answer (score 0):

Set the WebView to

`android:clickable="true"`

on your `RelativeLayout` of your Activity.

Then, set an OnClickListener to the WebView:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);
     }
});
```